# Orthogonal projection to the unit line (1,1,1,1) 4d

Tags: projection

I have data that shows the strength of an effect for 4 conditions over multiple features. (For each Features the Effect are always the same sign)
I want to find a way to order the features by the strength of the effect with a metric. In 2D I would make an orthogonal projection to the (1,1) line and use the distance of the projected point to the origin as a metric.

Is it possible to do the same thing in 4D?

I am not a very good mathematician, and I am really unsure about what I have done.
I was hoping to use the Pythagoras theorem and the dot product but I am not sure if what I done is correct. So could you tell me if my solution is correct? and if it is not correct how to achieve my goal?

Here the 3 dimension representation of the problem

[image]

We have a 4 D space with axes orthogonal and origins O as (0,0,0,0)

We have a point $P(P_x, P_y, P_z, P_w)$ that represents a feature. I want to make an orthogonal projection over the line w(1x,1y,1z,1w). $R$ the point of the orthogonal projection of P over w.
The distance $\lVert \vec{OR} \rVert$ is the score I look for.
If Pythagoras is applicable then:
$ \lVert \vec{OR} \rVert = \sqrt[2]{\lVert \vec{OP} \rVert^{2} - \lVert \vec{RP} \rVert^{2} }$

with $ \lVert \vec{RP} \rVert  = \sin{\theta} * \lVert \vec{OP} \rVert $

and to get theta we use the dot product between $\vec{OP}$ and any point of w. let pick w1 the point (1,1,1,1).

$$ \theta = \arccos{ \frac{ \vec{Ow1} . \vec{OP}} {\lVert \vec{Ow1} \rVert  * \lVert \vec{OP} \rVert }}$$

So in the end we obtain
$$  \lVert \vec{OR} \rVert = \sqrt[2]{\lVert \vec{OP} \rVert^{2} -  (\sin{\arccos{ \frac{ \vec{Ow1} . \vec{OP}} {\lVert \vec{Ow1} \rVert  * \lVert \vec{OP} \rVert }}} * \lVert \vec{OP} \rVert) ^{2}} $$

I don't know if it matter but I plan to use euclidean distance.

Comment: You need squares in $\lVert \vec{OR} \rVert = \sqrt{\lVert \vec{OP} \rVert\color{red}{^2} - \lVert \vec{RP} \rVert\color{red}{^2} }$

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you! I have updated it.